# DAL Interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I have an application where every table requires the following methods: SelectAll, SelectSingle, SetStatus, Save.

How can I set up an interface in the DAL for that? Do I absolutely have to use generics?

Clarification:

I want to know how I can create an interface that will work for every class in my dal, or if it is possible without generic list types.

Example interface, except you have to declare a return type for the methods in the interface:

```
public interface IBaseDB {
  public SelectAll();
  public SelectOne(int id);
  public void Save(object);
}
```

Example DAL class that implements the interface

```
public class UserDB : IBaseDB {
  public UserCollection SelectAll() { }
  public User SelectOne(int id) { }
  public void Save(User user) { }
}
```

Bottom line: I want to have a list of required methods for each class in the DAL, but each class in the DAL has a different return type for SelectAll and SelectOne. I don't know how to accomplish this yet.

Comment: You can use extension methods

Comment: This is a VERY broad question. Personally I often use an (or a series of) abstract bases which have things like Get(int id), Get(string uq) and so on. I override these for particular entities to give non-standard methods GetAllUsersLoggedInWithinXDays(int days);

Comment: This looks like project development requirement rather than a question: please narrow down your question. Regards,

Comment: Why don't you want to use generics? Generics would be perfect in this situation.

Comment: Are you trying to use DI concepts here ? I am trying to understand your goal to use interfaces here ?

Comment: I'm now down on the generics. I'm having trouble implementing it though. Anyone have an example? I don't know what DI is. My goal is... if I NEED four methods in every DAL class, then shouldn't I require them with an interface? And that led me here, because I wasn't sure how to with different return types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using generics, there aren't many reasons against this choice.
Without generics you'll have to cast instances or loosen up type checking by requiring `object` instances in the interface.
To better understand what you are doing, read about co- and contra-variance of .net generics.
Also, if possible, abandon completely this design (Data Access Layer, Business Logic Layer, Application and Presentation Layer) in favour of LinQ and repositories.

Some pointers:

- [Co/Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

Comment: You are correct. I guess I didn't want to use generics cause I didn't know how. It took some time but now I got it. I was able to set up an interface that had the methods I needed and everything seems ok. Or at least, it compiles.